# Animals in predicting disasters..!

Tags: zoology

I have been working on a project related to how different animals help in predicting natural disasters. But google searches and news only give evidence where animals showed some signs before disasters. But I am really interested to know what special sense they have due to which they can predict disasters early like earthquakes and tsunamis.
Particularly about the following animals -

1. Flamingos
2. Dogs
3. Elephants
4. Cats
5. Weasels
6. Bees
7. Bats
8. Snakes
9. Horses
10. Cows
11. Sharks

If anyone can suggest a book related to this or any website please mention .

Comment: Animals do not have any special sense which allows them to predict earthquakes or similar disasters, but humans *do* have an ability believe most anything they hear, or, especially, see written down.

Comment: I googled it and read it in a book . This site is for clearing misconception isn't it . Thanks for help

Comment: ReReading your question, I realize I probably misunderstood it. Your question is definitely opinion based. You should first find a claim that a given animal has some kind of supersensory power and then ask whether it is true on skeptics.SE

Comment: @Pi5 then please cite your sources in your question so we can evaluate them. Just because you read something on the internet or in a book doesn't mean it's true, unfortunately. Google "chemtrails" for an example.

Answer (score 2):

The question is currently too broad and your list of species is rather unexpected!

**Important Concepts**

You probably want to learn about the concept of [bioindicators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioindicator)

> Bioindicators are a species that can be used to monitor the health of an environment or ecosystem. They are any biological species or group of species whose function, population, or status can reveal the qualitative status of the environment. One example of a group of bio-indicators are the copepods and other small water crustaceans that are present in many water bodies. Such organisms can be monitored for changes (biochemical, physiological, or behavioural) that may indicate a problem within their ecosystem. Bio indicators can tell us about the cumulative effects of different pollutants in the ecosystem and about how long a problem may have been present, which physical and chemical testing cannot.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioindicator)

You also probably want to hear about [ecotoxicology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecotoxicology)

> Ecotoxicology is the study of the effects of toxic chemicals on biological organisms, especially at the population, community, ecosystem level. Ecotoxicology is a multidisciplinary field, which integrates toxicology and ecology.

I would advice that you read more on bioindicators and ecotoxicology.

**Why is the question too broad?**

If you are interested freshwater toxicity you will probably be interested copepods (as stated above). If you are interested in soil toxicity you will probably be interested in [Collembola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Springtail) (see [here](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:11267:ed-2:v1:en)). The question is currently too broad.

You should first address these questions to narrow down your question

- What disaster are you interested in?
- What kind of ecosystem are you interested in?

**Why is the list of species unexpected**

Typically, cats and horses are probably the worst bioindicators one could think of as their survival depend mostly on humans care and not so much on the environment.
It is unclear too why you are only interest in animal species.